# Deprecation of information in US visa application before the appointment date

Tags: visas, usa

I as a Russian national (and a Russian resident back then) applied for non-immigrant (B-2) US visa a year ago.
Due to the [suspension](https://ru.usembassy.gov/visas/) of U.S. Mission visa services in Russia, I've applied for my visa abroad (in Poland).
The appointment date I could secure was almost a year into the future, and is coming up soon. I stress that a time span between the application writing and the appointment is roughly one year.

I have reservations about my chances of getting visa with this application because *some* information, put into the application form a year ago, have became obsolete:

- My country of residence has changed
- My employment has changed
- My marital status has changed
- Reason for visit remains same in spirit but also changed: I wanted to attend a particular scientific conference, which has past already; it will be another conference in the future

My question is, with that much discrepancy between the reality and the one year-old statements in my old application, do I still stand a reasonable chance of getting a visa?
I want to estimate if this chance worth a trip to Poland for that appointment.

I understand that the US visa application once filed is not subject to editing or updating.
The alternative I am considering is to cancel the present application and to file a new one in the country, where I reside now.

Comment: Is the future conference date already decided on?

Comment: It is, yes. I target autumn 2023 now.

Comment: I'm not sure if things have changed recently, but we know some Russians who live near us and they have been denied entry into the US (on tourist visas) since the Russia/Ukraine conflict began.  Previously they were always admitted no problem.  No detention, no delays, just turned around at the (land) border due to having Russian passport.

Comment: How much do you value *not* having a visa denial on your travel history? With that much change since you applied, including the core purpose of the trip, if I were you I’d cancel and file a new application.

Comment: Especially with possible increased scrutiny, its better not to take the risk and submit another application, if you can afford to wait.

Answer (score 8):

I've reached out to the consulate; The answer was that the application form (DS-160) is indeed immutable, but the appointment is *not* strictly linked to the particular DS-160 ID once and for all.

So, what they've suggested and what I am going to implement is:

- [fill out](https://ceac.state.gov/ceac/) a new DS-160
- update my info at the [appointments website](https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/)
- then attend this appointment as it was planned.

I will update this answer too later.